# Carregar várias funções na pagina principal usando django

Tags: javascript, html, python, django, view

Estou com um problema ao tentar carregar alguns dados do banco de dados mysql usando django, tipo as funções só funcionam se eu atribuir no arquivo: **urls.py** o seguinte atributo:

```python
path('', views.countregistered)
```

Porém este atributo já é usado para a pagina **index.html** como mostra abaixo:

```python
path('', views.index, name='home')
```

Se eu inserir vários atributos como este apenas o primeiro é executado e o resto é ignorado, acredito não ser o correto, eu tenho várias funções para serem exibidas na página inicial que são carregadas apartir do banco de dados porém se eu digitar apenas o elemento com as funções na página html não funciona.
Grato pela ajuda, estou iniciando agora em django.

Answer (score 0):

A função path que você está utilizando serve para registrar URLs, sendo que o primeiro parâmetro que você passa para essa função é uma string com a URL que você deseja registrar. Então quando um usuário escreve no navegador o caminho para o seu site: "www.nome-do-seu-site.com/", o servidor tentará localizar uma URL que bate com a que o usuário informou.
Como você já mencionou, a página index já esta registrada com uma string vazia:

```
path('', views.index, name='home')
```

No entanto você está tentando registra outra URL com a mesma string:

```
path('', views.countregistered)
```

Assim quando o servidor tenta fazer a resolução da URL existem duas iguais, por isso apenas uma das funções é utilizada. Então quando você for registrar uma URL com o path, use diferentes strings, por exemplo:

```
path('count-registered/', views.countregistered)
```

Logo cada caminho direcionará para sua função correlatada.

Também sugiro que você leia a documentação para compreender melhor o uso da função path e boas práticas em seu uso.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/pt-br/3.2/ref/urls/